# split comma separated string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Manager Master table

[image]

And user table

[image]

I want comma separated manager name using master table .

i want result in this form

[image]

My query is like this

```
declare @ststring varchar(max)= select manager
 from customer

    CREATE TABLE #tblUserCustomer  ( inCustomerID iNT)

Insert into #tblUserCustomer
select stvalue from dbo.getlistfrmcommaseprated_int('1,2,4')
declare @stcscont varchar(1000)
select @stcscont = (select Um.Name + ',' from master um
                    join #tblUserCustomer T on t.inCustomerID = um.inuserid
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    )
print @stcscont
drop table #tblUserCustomer
```

this query can be help full for single data
but i have multiple row

Comment: i want manager name related manager id which is  given in user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your parse function, so I substituted mine.  `[dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]` which returns `RETVAL`

**Some Sample Data**

```
Declare @Manager table (ID int,Name varchar(25))
Insert Into @Manager values
(1,'Ajay'),
(2,'Sarita'),
(3,'Akash'),
(4,'Niti')

Declare @User table (ID int,Name varchar(25),Manager varchar(25))
Insert Into @User values
(1,'Javed','1,3'),
(2,'Ruma' ,'1,4')
```

**Actual Query**

```
Select A.*
      ,ManagerName = B.String
 From  @User A
 Cross Apply (
                Select String = Stuff((Select ',' +Name 
                  From (
                        Select M.Name,ML.RetSeq
                         From  @Manager M
                         Join  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Manager,',') ML
                           on  M.ID=ML.RetVal
                       ) X
                  Order By RetSeq
                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
              ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name    Manager   ManagerName
1   Javed   1,3       Ajay,Akash
2   Ruma    1,4       Ajay,Niti
```

> **EDIT - Added my Parse Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
--Performance On a 5,000 random sample -8K 77.8ms, -1M 79ms (+1.16), -- 91.66ms (+13.8)
```

Comment: hi it is giving error    "Invalid object name 'dbo.udf-Str-Parse."

Comment: @radhasingh Read the first line of my answer  Happy to supply my parse function.  Just assumed you didn't want two

Comment: @radhasingh added my parse function